# Can't quit from AppleScript application

Tags: applescript

I have an endless loop AppleScript application started at login. But there is a problem: I can not quit it unless im using SIGKILL. Is there any way to add some quit handler to it? Or there is better approach to make background process in AppleScript then "repeat - delay - end repeat"?

Comment: does command-period stop the applescript?

Comment: The AppleScript runner environment runs on a single thread. A background `process` is not possible.

Comment: I guess your current script is using on 'idle' handler. Then, add, in the current loop, a test to check something and quit. for instance, the test could be existence of folder with specific name on Desktop. so when you want to stop your idle handler in a clean way, just create the folder on desktop. your script could also ask you to confirm the quit and do some cleaning before.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're using an **on idle** handler, that's what you want to do.

```
on run
   -- prep code goes here
end run

on idle
    -- your code here
    display dialog "TEST" giving up after 4
    return 10
end idle
```

The above code will repeat itself every 10 seconds (based on the return value of 10, change as needed). The only other thing to keep in mind is this script needs to be saved as "Stay Open".

Hope this helps